# IO buffer design using tristate

Tags: buffer, verilog

Program for IO Buffer.
All ports are single bit as shown in the below block diagram. When op_en is high, data_out will be driving io_port. When op_en islow, io_port is tri-stated. Data_in will always be connected to io_port.

[image]

I tried below code.

```
module IOBuff(op_en,data_out,io_port,data_in);
input op_en;
inout io_port;
reg data_out;
reg data_in;
begin
assign io_port = op_en ? data_out : `bz
end
endmodule
```

I am new to verilog and tried above code but it's not complete and also how can we check whether our code is correct or not?

Comment: HINT: Look at your error messages. I see obvious port definition errors, typos on your assign statement, and a missing output driver. Two of those error types are compiling errors and will be reported in your log file

Comment: @Greg He will not see other errors because he used grawis instead of apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `'bz` expression you used grawis (`` ` ``) instead of apostrophe
   (`'`).
2. You don't finish assign expression with comma (`;`).
3. Your `data_out` is type of `reg` instead of `input` (depending on image).
4. Your `data_in` is type of `reg` instead of `output` (depending on image).
5. You should not place `assign` inside `begin end`.
6. You have unused `data_in` signal.

```systemverilog
module IOBuff(op_en, data_out, io_port, data_in);

    input op_en;
    inout io_port;
    input data_out;
    output data_in;

    assign io_port = op_en ? data_out : 'bz;

endmodule
```

Comment: in your code need to add ..   assign data_in = io_port;